# I want to handle crud operations on single view in mvc3 with different buttons along with javascript in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to handle crud operations on single view in mvc3 with different buttons along with javascript in mvc3.

Actually i have a view with account code and description fields.
i want to add,edit and delete record into sql server 2008 r2 database by using wcf services.
i want to use javascript for client side scripting. 
i want to call controller's method by javascript button click event.

Please tell me how i do it.

currently i have following javascript function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();

$('#sve').click(function () {
    var person = { AcCode: $('#AcCode').val(), Descrip: $('#Descrip').val(), AddOn: dd };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/Save',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(person),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (result) {
            //   $('#message').html('Record saved successfully' + result).fadeIn();
            alert("Record saved successfully");
        },
        error: function () {
            //    $('#message').html('Error Occurred').fadeIn(); 
            alert("Record not saved successfully");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

below is my controller code for save button

```
 [Authorize]
     // [Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")] 
     [HttpPost]
     [MultiButton(MatchFormKey = "action", MatchFormValue = "Save")]
            public ActionResult Save(AccntBD model)
     {
         CBSWCF.Account useInfo = new CBSWCF.Account();
         if (ModelState.IsValid)
         {
             if (!model.IsAcCodeExist(model.AcCode))
             {
                 string ObjUser = User.Identity.Name;
                 string ObjUid = string.Empty;
                   AcntEnt.AcCode = model.AcCode;
                 AcntEnt.Descrip = model.Descrip;
                  objSvc.ACodeSave2(AcntEnt);
                              }
             else
             {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", "Account Code Already Exist");
             }
         }
         else
         {
             ModelState.AddModelError("", "");
         }
         return View(model);
     }
```

i use following code to use multiple buttons in single view.
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class MultiButtonAttribute : ActionNameSelectorAttribute
    {
        public string MatchFormKey { get; set; }
        public string MatchFormValue { get; set; }

```
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[MatchFormKey] != null &&
            controllerContext.HttpContext.Request[MatchFormKey] == MatchFormValue;
    }
}
```

now problem is that my save function is not hit from javascript and message not saved successfuly is shown to me.
can anyone plz help me

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add the MultiButton attribute to the controller action if you are submitting the form via JavaScript the MultiButtonAttribute was created for when you wish to map submit Buttons to specific controller actions and this is possible because when you submit a form via a submit button the submit button name attribute is added to the post body with a its submit button specific value eg

```
<input type="submit" name="ButtonName" value="ButtonOne"/> <!-- would post ButtonName=ButtonOne -->
<input type="submit" name="ButtonName" value="ButtonTwo"/> <!-- would post ButtonNAme=ButtonTwo -->
```

If you wish to submit a form via javascript that will be routed to a different action based on the submit button you will be required to add the Button name and value to the querystring of the request

```
url: '/Home/Save?ButtonName=ButtonOne'
```